# Tabla de usuarios Mysql no guarda datos desde mi formulario PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

El problema es que cuando envio los datos a la BD me dice que se ha registrado correctamente pero al revisar la base de datos no estan guardados.
El log ni el formulario marcan ningún error por lo que no sé como resolverlo. El formulario tiene captcha también
A continuación les muestro el código de los 3 archivos que estoy usando.

Este es el código de mi pagina de registro:

```
<?php
    require 'conexion.php';
    require 'DBusuarios.php';
    $errors = array();
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $nombre = $mysqli -> real_escape_string ($_POST['nombre']);
    $ap = $mysqli -> real_escape_string ($_POST['ap']);
    $usuario = $mysqli -> real_escape_string ($_POST['usuario']);
    $password = $mysqli -> real_escape_string ($_POST['password']);
    $con_password = $mysqli -> real_escape_string ($_POST['con_password']);
    $email = $mysqli -> real_escape_string ($_POST['email']);
    $captcha = $mysqli -> real_escape_string ($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

    $tipo_usuario=2;
    $secret ='';
if(!$captcha){
    $errors[] = "Verifica el captcha";
}
if(isNull($nombre, $usuario, $ap, $password, $con_password, $email)){
    $errors[] = "Debe llenar todos los campos";
}
if(!isEmail($email)){
    $errors[] = "Dirección de correo invalida";
}
if(!validaPassword($password,$con_password)){
    $errors[] = "Las contraseñas no coinciden";
}
if(emailExiste($email)){
    $errors[] ="El correo electronico $email ya existe.";
}

if(count($errors)==0){
    $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$captcha");
    $arr = json_decode($response, TRUE);
        if($arr['success']){
            $pass_hash = hashPassword($password);
            $token = generateToken();
            $registro = registraUsuario ($nombre, $ap, $usuario, $pass_hash,$email, $token, $tipo_usuario);
```

En esta linea he agregado $nombre y al enviar el formulario sí muestra el nombre por lo que si contiene los datos

```
echo "Se ha registrado correctamente $nombre";
                echo "<br /><a href ='iniciar_sesion.php'>Iniciar sesion</a>";
                exit;

                }else{
                    $errors []= "Error al registrar";
                }
            }else{
                $errors[] = 'Error al comprobar Captcha';
            }
    }
    ?>


    <form class= "formulario" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
        <div class="text-center">
            <?php echo resultBlock($errors); ?><br />
        </div>
     <h1>Registrate</h1>
     <div class="contenedor">
     <div class="input-contenedor">
         <i class="fas fa-user icon"></i>
         <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre/s" required>
         </div>
                 <div class="input-contenedor">
                         <i class="fas fa-user icon"></i>
                         <input type="text" name="ap" placeholder="Apellidos" required>
                         </div>
                         <div class="input-contenedor">
                                 <i class="fas fa-user icon"></i>
                                 <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" required>
                                 </div>
         <div class="input-contenedor">
         <i class="fas fa-envelope icon"></i>
         <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Correo Electronico" value="<?php if(isset($email)) echo $email; ?>" required>
         </div>
                 <div class="input-contenedor">
        <i class="fas fa-key icon"></i>
         <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
         </div>
                 <div class="input-contenedor">
        <i class="fas fa-key icon"></i>
         <input type="password" name="con_password" placeholder="Confirmar contraseña" required>
         </div>
                 <label for="captcha" class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
                                <div class="g-recaptcha" class="text-center" data-sitekey=""></div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Registrarse" class="button">
```

Esta es la funcion

```
function registraUsuario($usuario, $pass_hash, $nombre, $ap, $email, $token, $tipo_usuario){
    global $mysqli;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, password, nombre, ap, correo, token, id_tipo) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssi', $usuario, $pass_hash, $nombre, $ap, $email, $token, $tipo_usuario);
    
}
```

Y esto es lo que tengo en conexion.php

```
    <?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db1");
or die("No hay conexion:" .mysqli_connect_error());
 ?>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, llevo varias horas y no encuentro el error.
El formulario ni el log arrojan error, al dar click en el botón registrarse se ejecuta correctamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes vació el campo de **database** a lo mejor necesita una database especifica, tambien puedes en lugar de comprobar con un if si salio mal la conexion puedes hacer `$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","") or die("No hay conexion:" .mysqli_connect_error());` de esa forma es en una sola linea

Comment: En tu código no veo nada que diga: *"Dice que sí registra"*. ¿Podrías decirnos por dónde está entrando el código para saber por dónde empezar a revisar? Gracias.

Comment: Hola, si tengo el nombre de la Base en conexion.php pero lo borré porque el trabajo es para una empresa.
Bueno, ejecuta la sentencia IF de errores, de que si ha sido registrado correctamente.

Comment: Okey, puedes editar la pregunta y poner lo que has intentado por favor

Comment: Ya he editado y no creo que el error venga de otro lado ya que lo demás son otras funciones como la verificacion de la contraseña y si funcionan, cada validacion funciona

Comment: El problema puede estar en la base de datos, ya sea que no te hayas conectado bien (que hayas escrito algun dato mal) o que tiene una configuracion distinta la base de datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una de las principales tareas cuando programas es pensar en todo lo que pueda salir mal y controlar esas situaciones.

En ese sentido, tu código en `registraUsuario()` es demasiado ingenuo. ¿Qué pasa si no hay conexión? ¿Qué pasa si el INSERT falla, por clave duplicada, por error de sintaxis o por otro motivo? Tu código no prevé nada de eso.

Entonces, vamos a verificar las cosas, para que quienes usen esa función sepan a qué atenerse.

Una función es algo que escribes por lo general una sola vez. Entonces ¡escríbela bien!, para que responda a todas las eventualidades.

Veamos:

```
function registraUsuario($usuario, $pass_hash, $nombre, $ap, $email, $token, $tipo_usuario){
    global $mysqli;
    if (!$mysqli) {
        return array('status'=>false, 'msg'=>'No hay conexión');
    } else {
        $sql="INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, password, nombre, ap, correo, token, id_tipo) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";   
        if ( $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) ) {
            $stmt->bind_param('ssssssi', $usuario, $pass_hash, $nombre, $ap, $email, $token, $tipo_usuario);
            if ( $stmt->execute() ) {
                return array('status'=>true, 'msg'=>"Filas insertadas: ".$stmt->affected_rows);
            } else {
                /*@todo Cambiar $stmt->error por mensaje personalizado*/
                return array('status'=>false, 'msg'=>'Error: '.$stmt->error);
            }
        } else {
                /*@todo Cambiar $mysqli->error por mensaje personalizado*/
                return array('status'=>false, 'msg'=>'Error: '.$mysqli->error);
        }       
    }
}
```

AHORA, en el contexto, tú no puedes llamar a `registrarUsuario()` y pasar a decir que se registró correctamente sin más. Debes verificar lo que ocurrió en el método y actuar en consecuencia.

Dado que escribimos un código robusto en `registrarUsuario()` ahora puedes hacer algo así:

```
$registro = registraUsuario ($nombre, $ap, $usuario, $pass_hash,$email, $token, $tipo_usuario);

if($registro['status']) {
    #El usuario se registró, actuar en consecuencia
} else {
    #Aquí deberías ver el mensaje de error. Puedes mostrarlo
    #o hacer lo que quieras. 
    #La cuestión es controlar el flujo del código
    echo $registro['msg'];
}
```

En programación es fundamental prever todo lo que podría salir mal y controlar los errores. El no control de errores es un error grave. Un código que no lo hace es un código incompleto. Aquí la lógica seguida es poner en un array las claves `status` para indicar si la función hizo o no lo que esperábamos, y otra clave `msg` que recoge mensajes informativos sobre lo ocurrido. Esos mensajes podrían ser mostrados al cliente o mandandos a un log de errores. Puedes optar por el estilo que quieras.

Comment: Wow, muchas gracias. La verdad es que no lo sabía, es la primera vez que trabajo en algo así, me ha ayudado muchisimo, ya he podido resolver el problema, era con la configuración de la tabla, en la columna no tenía suficiente espacio

Comment: @LissetK.Santes me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Te recomiendo que escribas bien tus funciones. A veces uno cree ganar tiempo escribiendo código corto (e ingenuo), porque es algo incómodo tantos `if` y demás y tu función inicial parecía más simpática. Pero a veces eso que parecía ahorrarte tiempo te hace perder horas, semanas, días... rompiéndote el coco por saber dónde está el error. Mientras que si inviertes tiempo diseñando el código luego encontrarás rápidamente cualquier error. He puesto dos `@todo` en el código porque en producción no conviene mostrar mensajes internos al usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que verifiques la inserción de los datos con un condicional de la siguiente manera, así podrás imprimir el error que te indica mysql al insertar los datos y comprobar el porque no esta almacenando la información en la BD.

Ejemplo:

```
function registraUsuario($usuario, $pass_hash, $nombre, $ap, $email, $token, 
$tipo_usuario){
    global $mysqli;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, password, nombre, ap, correo, token, id_tipo) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssi', $usuario, $pass_hash, $nombre, $ap, $email, $token, 
$tipo_usuario);

    if ($mysqli->query($stmt) == TRUE) {
        echo "Registro Insertado con Éxito"."<br/>";
    } else {
       echo "Error al insertar en la BD: " . $mysqli->error ."<br/>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Si estamos hablando de consultas preparadas entonces aqui `$mysqli->query($stmt) == TRUE` ¿no debería evaluar al método `execute` en todo caso?

Comment: Si podría evaluar el método execute al insertar de la siguiente manera tambien.

ejemplo:




if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios(usuario, password, nombre, ap, correo, token, id_tipo) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))) {
    echo "Falló la preparación: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}